# Two table in one controller

Tags: zend-framework3

I want use two model in one controller.

Controlle:
     protected $table;

```
    /**
     * Execute the request
     *
     * @param  MvcEvent $e
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected $commentTable;

    // Add this constructor:
    public function __construct(PostTable $table,CommentTable $commTable)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
       $this->commentTable = $commTable;
    }
```

Factory:

```
class PostControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null){
        $model = $container->get(PostTable::class);

        return new PostController($model);
    }
}
```

But I got error:

> :__construct() must be an instance of Post\Model\CommentTable, none given,

How use two tables in one controller?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing only `PostTable` but not `CommentTable` in your `PostController` constructor thought that needs to be there while creating factory for your controller. So you should do that in this way

```
class PostControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {
        $postTable = $container->get(PostTable::class);
        $commentTable = $container->get(CommentTable::class);

        return new PostController($postTable, $commentTable);
    }
}
```